# Which free C# library can generate PDF-417 barcodes?

Tags: c#, barcode

I'm in need of a **free** C# library which allows the creation of PDF-417 barcodes. However all the websites I've come across are commercial products. Can you recommend a free library?

Comment: Google turned up this SourceForge hit: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf417lib/files/pdf417lib/0.91/Pdf417lib-csharp-0.91.zip/download

Comment: Thanks, this might work.

Comment: Actually I'm having some trouble using the above library as there are no helpful examples or documentation. Has anyone used this library successfully?

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [ZXing.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net/) nuget package which will be more simple and easy to use.

```
private byte[] GenerateBarCodeZXing(string data)
{
    var writer = new BarcodeWriter
    {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.PDF_417,
        Options = new EncodingOptions { Width = 200, Height = 50 } //optional
    };
    var imgBitmap = writer.Write(data);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        imgBitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: This really works?

Comment: i believe it does, 4 ppl have upvoted it

Answer (score -1):

You can use [SharpPDF417](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpPdf417/) nuget package. It is fully free. But little bit wrapper code we need to write for getting byte[] or stream of bar code generated.

```
private byte[] GenerateBarCode(string data)
{
    Pdf417Generator gen = new Pdf417Generator(data);
    int bw = 2;
    int bh = 2;
    var barcode = gen.Encode();
    var width = barcode.Columns * bh;
    var height = barcode.Rows * bh;
    Byte[] imgData;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Image bmp = new Bitmap(width, height))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {


                int y = 0;
                for (int r = 0; r < barcode.Rows; ++r)
                {
                    int x = 0;
                    for (int c = 0; c < barcode.Columns; ++c)
                    {
                        if (barcode.RawData[r][c] == 1)
                        {
                            graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x, y, bw, bh);
                        }
                        x += bw;
                    }
                    y += bh;
                }
            }
            bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
        }

        imgData = stream.ToArray();
    }
    return imgData;
}
```

You can use my above method to get byte array for barcode generated.

Comment: This doesn't work. It produces a barcode that looks just fine but I cannot read it with my phone, an online barcode recognizer nor a motorola scanner. The ZXing.net package I can read it but I'm having a nightmare getting the aspect ratio correct

Comment: Ditto, Generated it with level 0 (unscannable), level 4 (text was duplicated) and level 8 (text was cut-off).  Opted to go compare the generated barcode with one of the online scanners and no, this does not create valid pdf417 barcodes.